# Add cell value to email subject line in Google Script

Tags: email, google-apps-script, cell, return-value

I'm not a programmer, so I'm trying to keep this nice and simple.
I've created a script with which I can send a Google Sheet as a pdf attachment to multiple email addresses. This all works as it should.

However, I would also like to include that Sheet's B7 cell value in the email subject line:
"Subject line ". What is the easiest way to do this?

This is the code I have so far:

```
function sendReport() {
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Artikelen").hideSheet();
var message = {
to: "emailadresses",
subject: "Subject line",
body: "TEXT",
name: "NAME",
attachments: [SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getAs(MimeType.PDF).setName("Transportaanvraag")]
}
MailApp.sendEmail(message);
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Artikelen").activate();
}
```

I've tried several scripts from other similar issues, but I keep getting a SyntaxError.
This is the first script I've ever tried my hand on, so the solution is probably simple. Thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
function sendReport() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Artikelen");

  // Get the value of cell B7
  var cellB7Value = sheet.getRange("B7").getValue();

  // Define an array of email addresses
  var emailAddresses = ["email1@example.com", "email2@example.com", "email3@example.com"];

  var message = {
    to: emailAddresses.join(), // Join the email addresses with commas
    // Include the value of B7 in the subject line
    subject: "Subject line " + cellB7Value,
    body: "Dear ...,\n\nPlease find attached ...\n\nRegards,",
    name: "NAME",
    attachments: [SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getAs(MimeType.PDF).setName("Transportaanvraag")]
  };

  MailApp.sendEmail(message);
}
```

Comment: Answered just before I shared my modified code, but that is the way I would go about it as well.

Comment: If the answer is useful to you and correct, you can accept it. Thank you

Comment: It works, thank you so much!